# Chrome browser in Android not allowing auto video playback without user ineraction

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview, html5-video

We have a web based digital signage application which we are converting to run on Android (Not native) (and aimed to more media players than tablets)- The issue we are having is that when we create playlists (images and videos-Mp4) of media items (from local directory) we cant seem to get the video files to play without user interaction.

It seems chrome is blocking this, anyone else experience this? Or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's issue! Mobile WebKit requires user interaction to load or play media, done because of bandwidth limitations.

In link below described way to download media without user interaction, but for playing you need some user generated event 
['touchstart', 'touchend', 'touchmove', 'touchleave', 'touchcancel', 'click', 'keydown', 'keyup', 'keypress']

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132691

Answer (score 0):

Android WebView has a setting named [MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)) which controls this behaviour. But it's not possible to do this in Chrome.